# Return string from UnityWebGL jslib

Tags: javascript, html, unity-game-engine, get, unity-webgl

I want use jslib  to get **url parameter**

code like this

jslib

```
  GetUrl: function(){
  var s ="";
  var strUrl = window.location.search;
  var getSearch = strUrl.split("?");
  var getPara = getSearch[1].split("&");
  var v1 = getPara[0].split("=");
        alert(v1[1]);
   return v1[1];
  },
});
```

c#

```
[DllImport("__Internal")]
public static extern string GetUrl();


void Start () {
    TextShow.text = GetUrl();
}
```

When run alert from jslib , I see right string show in alert but UGUI Text shows nothing.

Why did this happen?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To return `string` from Javascript to Unity, you must use `_malloc` to allocate memory then `writeStringToMemory` to copy the `string` data from your `v1[1]` variable into the newly allocated memory then return that.

```
GetUrl: function()
{
  var s ="";
  var strUrl = window.location.search;
  var getSearch = strUrl.split("?");
  var getPara = getSearch[1].split("&");
  var v1 = getPara[0].split("=");
  alert(v1[1]);


   //Allocate memory space
   var buffer = _malloc(lengthBytesUTF8(v1[1]) + 1);
   //Copy old data to the new one then return it
   writeStringToMemory(v1[1], buffer);
   return buffer;
}
```

The `writeStringToMemory` function seems to be [deprecated](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/emscripten-discuss/BoFjUXAE0D4) now but you can still do the-same thing with `stringToUTF8` and proving the size of the string in its third argument.

```
GetUrl: function()
{
  var s ="";
  var strUrl = window.location.search;
  var getSearch = strUrl.split("?");
  var getPara = getSearch[1].split("&");
  var v1 = getPara[0].split("=");
  alert(v1[1]);


   //Get size of the string
   var bufferSize = lengthBytesUTF8(v1[1]) + 1;
   //Allocate memory space
   var buffer = _malloc(bufferSize);
   //Copy old data to the new one then return it
   stringToUTF8(v1[1], buffer, bufferSize);
   return buffer;
}
```

Comment: it work! thank!
this is more complicated than I expected.