# Send string to UnityWebGL jslib

Tags: javascript, html, unity-game-engine, unity-webgl

I tried using **jslib** to show alert message , but the alert windows show strange numbers for me.

like 48616488  58926312 20535112 21654936 25634800

But I send same string , what I get this numbers?

This is code:

jslib

```
  IAUDIO: function (str) {
            alert(str);
  }
```

c#

```
    [DllImport("__Internal")]
    public static extern void IAUDIO(string s);

    void SendData(){
    IAUDIO("Test");
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just like your [last](https://stackoverflow.com/q/52111679/3785314) question. You can't use `string` sent from C# directly. The `string` is passed as a pointer and you need a way to access it from the memory. The [`Pointer_stringify`](https://kripken.github.io/emscripten-site/docs/api_reference/preamble.js.html#Pointer_stringify) function is used for this.

```
IAUDIO: function (str) 
{
    alert(Pointer_stringify(str));
},
```

Your C# code looks fine.

Comment: cool , I thought this would be similar to javascript on html.

Comment: No. It's like making a call from compiled C code to JavaScript. You'll understand the whole thing if you read [this](https://kripken.github.io/emscripten-site/docs/api_reference/preamble.js.html).

Comment: Then learn it. You will need it someday if you need to make a native plugin in Unity. You will need to understand pointers in C/C++ to do any useful stuff without running into crashing or weird issues like the one in your question.